# How to hide child component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'am trying to hide  child component after clicking anchor tag. I am passing value from parent to child.

If I click anchor tag particular that anchor tag section is hiding.i would like to hide complete child component and i have to open new components after clicking anchor tag how can  do that.

parent COMPONENT:

```
    <li class="slds-feed__item">
       <c:S360_ListingSubArticle article="{!ar}"/> 
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Childcomponent:

```
      <aura:attribute name="article" type="Article__kav"/>
<aura:attribute name="enableDetail" type="boolean" default="true"/>

    <aura:if isTrue=”{!v. enableDetail}”>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_9-of-12" style="padding-left:1em;">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
               <a onclick="{!c.articleUrl}" >
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>
                    <div class="articleheading"> {!v.article.UrlName} </div>    
                </span>
            </div>
            </a>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>{!v.article.Article_Description__c}</span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

```
  ({
      articleUrl: function(component, event, helper) {
   var articleId=component.get("v.article.Id");
   component.set("v.enableDetail",false);
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your requirements are or the ultimate behavior you are expecting is. Note that there are OOTB lightnin gcomponents that can help you achieve this, such as [lightning:accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_accordion.htm):

```
   <lightning:accordion activeSectionName="B">
     <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="Accordion Title A">This is the content area for section A</lightning:accordionSection>
     <lightning:accordionSection name="B" label="Accordion Title B">This is the content area for section B</lightning:accordionSection>
     <lightning:accordionSection name="C" label="Accordion Title C">This is the content area for section C</lightning:accordionSection>
   </lightning:accordion>
```

As a side note, this was mentioned to you in another post, [avoid using anchor tags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm) if you will be wanting to redirect users to anoethr lightning page, record or component:

> Don’t hard code or dynamically generate Salesforce URLs in the href
>   attribute of an  tag. Use events, such as force:navigateToSObject
>   or force:navigateToURL, instead.

If you are trying to hide elements in your page after them being selected, you can use the [$A.Util.togleClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm) which adds or removes a class you have defined.

Overall, you might want to reconsider using anchors for whatever it is you are trying to develop based on your recent question history and leverage lightning:input and or lightning:buttons.

If you have a moment to go through the [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm?search_text=reference) from the lightning component developer guide, it might help you better leverage OOTB events and functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide complete child components place anchor tag on parent component and do the stuffs there.

Example

**Component:**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="enableDetail" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <a onclick="{!c.articleUrl}" >test</a>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.enableDetail}">
        <aura:iteration items="[1,2,3,4]" var="acc">
            <c:child/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    articleUrl: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.enableDetail",!component.get("v.enableDetail"));
    }
})
```

Comment: ya but...if you place above aura:iteration it will select the values in child..suppose your  child component contains title and description..it will select both title&description.i would like to add anchore for title

Comment: I cant get you clearly, if you want to hide all child components or particular component that you are clicking and what do you mean "like to add anchore for title "